# How to fetch total number of posts published by a profile

Tags: facebook

Currently from user table, we are getting only wall_count (The number of Wall posts for the user being queried). I'm not actually getting what this is but it is definitely not the total number of posts published by the profile.

Can you please let me know what is wall_count and how can I get the total number of posts published by a profile.

Comment: Why do you say it's not the number of posts on that user's timeline? It's documented as being that